# How to access Android Automotive OS emulators data/data folder in mac?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-automotive, androidautomotiveemulator, androidautomotiveos

I cannot access the data/data folder where my application package exists in the Android Automotive OS emulator.

If I go in Android Studio-->Device Manager-->data->data here my package name also not visible.

How can I access files folder of my package name.

I have did
adb shell
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/"

gives me
"/system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found" error.

Please help me to access this files folder.